# Is it possible to declare associative array in the function caller?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to declare associative array in the argument of function in  - is it possible??

this code it's not working..

```
<a href="javascript:functionName(new Array('cool'=>'Mustang','family'=>'Station'))">click</a>
```

that code is working - is it the only way?

```
<script>
    var my_cars= new Array()
    my_cars["cool"]="Mustang";
    my_cars["family"]="Station";
</script>

<a href="javascript:functionName(my_cars)">click</a>
```

Comment: why would you prefer the first way? generally none or as little as possible javascript should be in your html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're trying to using PHP syntax in Javascript.

You need to use Javascript syntax to create an object literal:

```
functionName({ cool: "Mustang", family: "Station" });
```

Answer (score 10):

Don't use "new Array()" when all you want is an object with strings as property names:

```
var my_cars = {};
my_cars["cool"]="Mustang";
my_cars["family"]="Station";
```

or just

```
var my_cars = {
  cool: 'Mustang', family: 'Station'
};
```

Arrays are intended to support integer-indexed properties, and they also maintain the "length" of the list of integer-indexed properties automatically (well, the "conceptual" length).

Answer (score 6):

This will work.

`<a href="javascript:functionName({'cool':'Mustang','family':'Station'})">click</a>`

In JS [Objects are associate arrays](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html)